# Excel - Removing a Worksheet Before "Enable Content" Disables Macro's

Tags: vba, excel

I have a rather interesting issue in excel(Office 365 Version 1708) that seems to be affecting every file that contains Macros. If I place a untrusted XLSM file containing VBA Macro's in a untrusted location and open the file I'm greeted with the following message:

[image]

If I click "Enable Editing", I am able to edit the file but I also get the following message:

[image]

Sometime, if I delete a worksheet in the file BEFORE clicking "Enable Content"; content is not enabled. I am not able to run any VBA Macro's triggered by [Custom Ribbon Events](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2014/10/02/add-your-own-icon-to-an-excel-custom-ribbon-tab/), and code in "Workbook_Open" does not trigger and does not run. To use any Macro's in the file, it needs to be closed and reopened.

Other times, I find that once you delete a worksheet, that the "Enable Content" button disappears, and again the file has to be closed/reopened to access any Macro's.

Is this intended behavior? It's very strange... Is there any way to modify this behavior to allow VBA Macro's to run after the user clicks "Enable Content", and to persist this message after the user delete's a worksheet?

Comment: Once you start working with a file, Excel pretty soon decides you don't want to enable macros if you haven't already clicked "Enable": as you note you need to re-open the file to get that button back.  I've not seen the case where the "enable" button is still there but doesn't do anything. Could your sheet deletion have maybe caused a compile error in the VB project?

Comment: As @Tim suggested, I'm also thinking the sheet you deleted has code attached to it that contains a variable (etc) that's referenced ny a module.  (You can confirm by right clicking the worksheets' tab and choosing "view code".)

Comment: I have code attached to "ThisWorkbook" and a number of Forms, Modules, Class Modules, but absolutely nothing attached to any worksheet, it is hard to reproduce though, on my machine I get the disappearing button, on a different one it stays but doesn't work, either way users complain that the application "doesn't work", it really seems like this particular thing is completely outside of my control :(